# Assign dependencies python version while brew installing

Tags: macos, homebrew, autojump

New for homebrew

Now want to install `autojump` via `brew install autojump`, which need to install `python@3.9` as denpendency. I already have `python@3.8` installed via brew and don't want an another version.

`python@3.8` also satisfy `autojump` from it's homgpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible, that's not how Homebrew works.

Installing `autojump` with homebrew is basically

1. Creating a virtual environment with Python@3.9 (Homebrew always chooses the latest Python)
2. Install `autojump` package in that environment.

Unless you modify the `autojump` homebrew formula, You can't reuse `python@3.8`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
brew install autojump --ignore-dependencies
```